# Operator overloading of C++ STL map with custom classes

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I have a doubt regarding using stl map in C++. I know using map with custom classes I need to overload "<" operator to make map work. But how do I define it in a meaningful way. For example I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct box{
    int e,s,w;
    box(): e(-1), s(-2), w(-3)
    {}

       bool operator< (const box& lhs) const
       {
           return e < lhs.e;
       }

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    map<box, int> hashtable;
    box b;
    hashtable[b] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I have overloaded the < operator very trivially. I could have overloaded it as follows too

```
bool operator< (const box& lhs) const
{
    return w+s+e < lhs.e+lhs.s+lhs.w;
}
```

And there are other ways too. So my question is, does this, overloading of < operator, affect the search, delete time of accessing the elements in map. I mean does it affect hashing part of the maps. If so, what is the best way to overload < operator.

My only motive here is to store pairs of box and int (see in the main function), so that I can access them in O(log(n)) time.

**UPDATE**

I figured that having a shitty comparator does not affect the access, delete time of maps but rather have a impact on the keys present in the map. For example if my comparator were the following

```
bool operator< (const box& lhs) const
{
    return e < lhs.e;
}
```

and now lets say I two tuples (e,s,w) as (1,2,3) and (1,3,4). I want to insert it into the above map. Now because I have comparator which solely determines on the basis of value of "e", it will reject the second tuple. So finally the map will contains the (1,2,3) not the other tuples.

The best way to write a comparator is using [std::tie](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tie/), as suggested by @edgar in the accepted answer.

```
bool operator< (const box& lhs) const
{
    return std::tie(e,w,s) < std::tie(lhs.e,lhs.w,lhs.s);
}
```

In this two tuples are different even if the tuples have different ordering. I had a requirement of that in my question. For example (1,2,3) is different than (2,1,3). Had I use the following comparator

```
bool operator< (const box& lhs) const
{
    return e+w+s < lhs.e+lhs.w+lhs.s;
}
```

Again only the first tuple would have made it because both these tuples have same sum, so again not a good comparator.

Comment: FYI, a std::map is not a hashtable, and doesn't use hashing. For that, you would want std::unordered_map.

Comment: With variable names like `e`, `w` and `s`, it's not easy to understand what `operator<` means for this class.

Comment: @PaulRooney, for my case I was solving the box stacking problem. so it was length, breath, height of the boxes. I wanted to put these in the tree if there was different tupple, which is solved by tie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is, does this, overloading of < operator, affect the
>   search, delete time of accessing the elements in map.

No, it is guaranteed that search, deletion and accessing elements are performed in logarithmic time.

> I mean does it affect hashing part of the maps.

*std::map* is not *std::unordered_map*, so there is no hashing here.

> If so, what is the best way to overload < operator.

I suppose that the standard way now is to use [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
bool operator<(const box& lhs) const
{
    return std::tie(e, s, w) < std::tie(lhs.e, lhs.s, lhs.w);
}
```

Comment: thanks edgar for answering.. So my operator overloading method and your suggested one won't have any effect on the access, deleting time of the tree... is that right?

Comment: @paramvir yes, definitely. You can check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map for the details of all the methods.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is not a hash map, it's a binary tree.

`operator<` is invoked every time the tree is accessed, once for each lookup step. So obviously the complexity of it affects performance (overhead aside, the cost of e.g. a lookup in an `std::map` is proportional to the cost of `operator<`).

`std::unordered_map` is a hash map. But for that you need to implement `std::hash<box>` and `std::equal_to<box>` (hashing and equality functors). `operator<` isn't used in that case.

Comment: can you elaborate on the part of "affects performance"... Because in the docs, they say it is lograthimic time

Comment: @paramvir  It will use `operator<` O(ln(n)) times for each insertion, deletion or lookup